# Shiny Download Plot - only getting htm files (no png)

Tags: r, shiny, png

For the life of me I can't figure out what's going on.  I want to include a download button in my app for plots (png files).  I have the following code, when I push the download button I get the following pop up "download.htm".  Can anyone see where the error is:

ui.R part with downloadbutton:

```
tabPanel("BOOKINGS", 
br(), br(),
fluidRow(column(12, "BOOKINGS",
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("mcsoPlot")),
tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("BOOKINGS")), 
br(),
downloadButton(outputId = "down", label = "Download the plot")
```

server.R part related to graph and download button:

```
buildplot <- function(){
p <- ggplot(selectedData(), aes(x = MONTH, group = TYPE, color = TYPE)) +
 geom_line(stat = "count", size = 1.5)  
p
}

output$down <- downloadHandler(
filename =  "Shinyplot.png",

content = function(file) {
png(file) # open the png device
buildplot()
dev.off()  # turn the device off

} 
)
```

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and wanted to post the answer because I didn't run across this in other posts and someone may make the same mistake.

In the ui.R script, the downloadbutton script cannot be located within the same fluidRow as the plots.  I essentially created another fluidRow and placed the download buttons there.  Final ui.R example would be:

```
fluidRow(column(12, "BOOKINGS",
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("mcsoPlot")),
tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("BOOKINGS")), 
br(),
fluidRow(column(12, "",
downloadButton(outputId = "down", label = "Download the plot")))
))))
```